How to replace all occurrences of comma separated error
I have below two tables in a SQL Server database. I have a procedure which performs validation for each record on Transactions table & saves the comma separated error in the Error_Messages column.
ErrorMessages table contains all the error messages.
CREATE TABLE dbo.Transactions
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Error_Messages VARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ErrorMessages
(
    Field_Type varchar(100), 
    Code VARCHAR(100), 
    Error_Msg VARCHAR(300) 
)

TRUNCATE TABLE Transactions

INSERT INTO Transactions(Error_Messages) 
VALUES ('First Name should not contain special symbols, first name length should be less than 250 chars, last name is mandatory');

TRUNCATE TABLE ErrorMessages

INSERT INTO ErrorMessages 
VALUES ('FirstName', 'FirstName_Symbol', 'First Name should not contain special symbols,');
INSERT INTO ErrorMessages 
VALUES ('FirstName', 'FirstName_Length', 'First name length should be less than 250 chars,');
INSERT INTO ErrorMessages 
VALUES ('LastName', 'LastName_Mandatory', 'Last name is mandatory,');

User can fix the error & try to run the validation again. How can I replace all occurrences of errors from Error_Messages column before running the validation.
For eg. If I am running the validation for field type "FirstName" then I will replace all the errors related to first name from Error_messages column of the Transactions table, & keeping rest of the errors as is.

This doesn't sound like a great design. select string_agg(Error_Messages, ', ') from Transactions cross apply string_split(Error_Messages, ',') e where ltrim(e.value) not in (select Error_Msg from dbo.ErrorMessages where Field_Type = 'FirstName') This wouldn't automatically preserve the order either. Why don't you just store error id numbers in separate rows so you don't have to translate back and forth?

Agree it would be much better to store the errors in separate rows. But also what you are asking for it just using a Replace() function in TSQL - shouldn't be too hard to work out. Have you tried anything yet?

I need to display the error on UI. I can split the comma separated string & show summary on UI. I am checking your query & it's giving me wrong output. just fyi, in the sample, error message should only contain "Last name is mandatory" rest should get replaced.
https://dbfiddle.uk/xmhFibL8

@topsail my approach was to first split the error message in transaction table in multiple rows then filter out by matching error message table then again transform it back to comma separated string & then update this final value. Transaction table is large & this is taking little more time

You're doing weird stuff with commas and I was aggregating the wrong value: select string_agg(ltrim(value + ','), ' ') from Transactions cross apply string_split(Error_Messages, ',') e where ltrim(e.value + ',') not in (select Error_Msg from dbo.ErrorMessages where Field_Type = 'FirstName' and Error_Msg is not null) https://dbfiddle.uk/4u9PzP7d

@shawnt00 Thanks this is working for me. If you put in answers, I can mark.

Also BTW: "How can I replace all occurrences of errors from Error_Messages column before running the validation" ... this is just Update Table Set ErrorMessages = '' Then rerun the validation and save the new (appropriate) error messages. And if you table is so large you have problems you probably are making things worse by saving strings .... save the error IDs only, and create the messages at runtime from the IDs. I wouldn't even bother saving such transient error messages in a database. So many odd things going on here.

@topsail yes it make sense to store error id instead of whole error. I am building some new requirement on existing functionalities which would require me more time for redesign. I don't want reset error message as the whole validation procedure takes above 1 minute to complete. Thanks for your suggestion.

You can always split the text on commas and then match against the original text to eliminate the ones with the Field_Type being reset:
select string_agg(ltrim(value + ','), ' ')
from Transactions cross apply string_split(Error_Messages, ',') e
where ltrim(e.value + ',') not in (
    select Error_Msg from dbo.ErrorMessages
    where Field_Type = 'FirstName' and Error_Msg is not null
);

https://dbfiddle.uk/4u9PzP7d
Caveats include that messages can't have embedded commas and that the source messages can never be changed if they're not kept in sync.
